# Skellam Distribution

Tags: r, statistics

As u guys know the Skellam package was removed from CRAN (dont ask why). After some time of Internet research, I couldnt find a skellam pmf function, so I wrote it myself.

Comment: When someone says "dont ask why" I am very tempted to ask "why?". Why?

Comment: well im not from CRARN, u know ;) mb it was poorly documented or smth

Comment: You can always get the old version from the archive. Then you could ask the maintainer Jerry W. Lewis <JWLewis53@verizon.net>. The version on the archive passes R CMD CHECK for me. And installs. And runs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
skellam <- function(k,mu1,mu2){
  return(exp(-mu1-mu2)*((mu1/mu2)^(k/2))*besselI(2*sqrt(mu1*mu2),k))
}
```

Comment: See also `dskellam` in `VGAM`.  The distributions task view is good for finding this sort of function.  http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html

Comment: That package is missing a cumulative mass function, in case you want to contribute.

Comment: That's nice, but given the simplicity of this function, what's the point?  Anyone who "should" be using a skellam function can copy it right out of wikipedia.